# DotNet Core Api - Different Authentication for specific endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, jwt

I have a tricky scenario -
I have a Dotnet Core web api that uses Jwt bearer token for auth.
We have a use case that we would like to generate a slightly different bearer token for a subset of endpoints - this bearer token has different claims than the main token.
I am able to generate the new token and claims - its is Authenticated to the system and works, BUT I dont want it to work on ALL endpoints.

It would need to be something like:
bearer_token1 => can access all endpoints and work (this is our current bearer token)
bearer_token2 => can access SOME endpoints BUT NOT ALL (this is our new token)

endpoint1 needs to work ONLY with bearer_token1.If a user tries to use  bearer_token2, they would get a 401 error 
endpoint2 needs to work bearer_token1 OR bearer_token2.

I can obviously add code to each endpoint to look at the claims and fail bearer_token2 where needed, but we have a lot of endpoints.

Is there a way to specify that a controller needs to authorize with a specific token?

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify any number of different policies, with any set of requirements.

The default policy only checks that the user is authenticated. You can replace the default policy to specify some other requirement that you can meet during your normal login process. With some other policy for your new login tokens. For example;

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
    var builder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
    builder.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    builder.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "all_access");
    o.DefaultPolicy = builder.Build();

    o.AddPolicy("OtherPolicy", b => {
        b.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        b.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        b.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "some_access");
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this will work - I am having trouble with allowing BOTH bearer_token1 and bearer_token2 to authorize on a specific controller.
If I add [Authorize(Policy = "SharedToken")] to the specific endpoint in a controller that already has  [Authorize] at the base, it does not allow the default tokens to work - I need them to also work.

Comment: You'll need to distinguish your tokens somehow, so you can link their attributes to your login policies.

Comment: I ended up creating a new custom policy RequireAssertion that allows for either the new or old token for this policy (supports both) and then added a RequireClaim onto the default policy that looks for a unique claim on the old token - so now the existing endpoints forbid the new token and the endpoints decorated with the new policy in the [Authorize] attribute accept both!
MSFT did a great job with this- and thanks again for pointing me in this direction!

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple authentication schemes for different bear token, you could use Authorize attribute to set the AuthenticationSchemes.

You could set the Authorize AuthenticationScheme for specific controller based on your opinion. Like below:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = 
    JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```